Zoom not honoring image region in Mirador
I have a IIIF manifest I render via Loris and display via Mirador. The images I have currently have are microform images where two pages of a manuscript appear. I have changed my manifest to show only the page I wish to work with using the manifest below.  The problem I'm running into is that the viewer window does not respect the percentages laid out in the resource@id section. It does respect the same URI for the thumbnail, which makes me think it is a Mirador, not Loris, issue and that the issue may be in how I'm constructing the manifest. I'm not sure what I'm missing, though. Any help would be appreciated.
{
    "@context": "http://iiif.io/api/presentation/2/context.json",
    "@id": "http://167.172.119.13/manifests/Lydgate/Mumming_Eltham/Additional_29729.json",
    "@type": "sc:Manifest",
    "description": "Additional_29729 Mumming at Eltham manifest",
    "label": "A Mumming at Eltham: Additional 29729 verses",
    "sequences": [{
        "@type": "sc:Sequence",
        "label": "Additional 29729 f135v to f136r",
        "canvases": [
            {
                "@id": "http://167.172.119.13/manifests/Lydgate/Mumming_Eltham/canvas/Additional_29729_f135v",
                "@type": "sc:Canvas",
                "label": "folio 135v.",
                "width": 8661,
                "height": 6366,
                "images": [{
                    "@type": "oa:Annotation",
                    "motivation": "sc:painting",
                    "resource": {
                        "@id": "http://167.172.119.13/loris/Additional_29729/136.tif/pct:5,1,47,98/full/0/default.jpg",
                        "@type": "dctypes:Image",
                        "format": "image/jpeg",
                        "height": 6366,
                        "width": 8661,
                        "service": {
                            "@id": "http://167.172.119.13/loris/Additional_29729/136.tif",
                            "profile": "http://library.stanford.edu/iiif/image-api/1.1/conformance.html#level1"
                        }
                    },
                    "on": "http://167.172.119.13/manifests/Lydgate/Mumming_Eltham/canvas/Additional_29729_f135v"
                }],
                "thumbnail": {"@id": "http://167.172.119.13/loris/Additional_29729/136.tif/pct:5,1,47,98/full/0/default.jpg"}
            }
        ]
    }]
}

